# formal argument "ylim" matched by multiple actual arguments error using raster

Tags: r, shiny

Currently I have a problem with the raster package trying to import some images into a program. It doesn't accept the argument ylim yielding the error above, but when I try to use ylim2 or any other variation, it says "ylim2" is not a graphical parameter. So I wonder what are the actual arguments that are matched by ylim?

```
output$TLC_MS_pict.1 <- renderPlot({
par(mar=c(0,0,3,0))
raster(TLC_MS_files()[[1]],main=TLC_MS_files_name()[1],xlim=c(0,TLC_MS_x_width),ylim=c(0,TLC_MS_y_height))
})
output$TLC_MS_pict.1.zoom <- renderPlot({
par(mar=c(0,0,3,0))
raster(TLC_MS_files()[[1]],main=TLC_MS_files_name()[1],xlim=TLC_MS_zoom$x,ylim=TLC_MS_zoom$y)
if(!is.null(TLC_MS_coord$x)){
text(x=TLC_MS_coord$x*10,y=TLC_MS_coord$y*10-10,label=seq(length(TLC_MS_coord$x)),col=input$TLC_MS_color,pos = 3,cex=0.5)
symbols(x=TLC_MS_coord$x*10,y=TLC_MS_coord$y*10,fg=input$TLC_MS_color,inches = F,add = T,rectangles = cbind(rep(4*10,length(TLC_MS_coord$x)),rep(2*10,length(TLC_MS_coord$x))))
```

Answer (score 0):

First try a simple example. The `raster` method simply does not have these arguments; they are arguments to `plot`. Perhaps this is because of a misplaced parenthesis. Start with something simple like this

```
f <- TLC_MS_files()[[1]]
r <- raster(f)
output$TLC_MS_pict.1 <- renderPlot(
      plot(r, main="test")
)
```